# How to get the td that contains tr with a button that has a specific attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get all the tds in a table that contain a tr with a button to which I have specified an attribute ("boolean") with a true or false value. I need to get each td that have that attribute with value true but I can't figure out how to get it using jquery.

The structure would be the following:

```
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr row-id="1">
            <td class="text-left">
                            <div />
            </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="true">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr row-id="2">
            <td class="text-left">
                <div />
                        </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="false">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr row-id="3">
            <td class="text-left">
                <div />
            </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="true">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried to do something like this:

```
function colour() {
    $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
        let colour = $(this).children("td")[1];     
    }
}
```

But I can't go from there to get those td since I have no experience with jquery

How could I get the td with row-id 1 and 3 with Jquery and then apply a style to those td?
Thanks in advance

Comment: In this way you can get all td who contains buttons those have boolean true. Please let me know if it resolve your issue?
$("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
    if($(this).find('button').attr('boolean')=="true"){ 
        let colour = $(this).children("td")[1];     
        console.log(colour);
        }
    })

Comment: get what "td" The one in the same row without the button? What exactly is the end result?

Comment: @epascarello The final result that I need is to obtain the 2 rows that contain in one of their td a button with that attribute set to true. In the end, we can apply a red background-color to those rows, for example.

Comment: @Ashish in the other comment I put the final result that I need. Thanks for the answer but it's not quite what I need

Comment: @Alvarofb7 I updated my code for adding style as well. Can I check your updated code?

Comment: @Alvarofb7 thanks for commenting. Could you please mark it green tick. It will help me to encourage resolving more issues of others?

Comment: @Ashish I put the green tick. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a has selector with attribute selector

```js
var trs = $('tr:has(button[boolean="true"])');
console.log(trs);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr row-id="1">
            <td class="text-left">
                            <div />
            </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="true">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr row-id="2">
            <td class="text-left">
                <div />
                        </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="false">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr row-id="3">
            <td class="text-left">
                <div />
            </td>
            <td class="text-left td-button">
                <button boolean="true">Button</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("#table tbody tr").each(function() { 
      //Filter to iterate those td's which contain Boolean true                                             
     if($(this).find('button').attr('boolean')=="true"){
      let colour = $(this).children("td")[1]; 
      colour.style.backgroundColor="red";
      console.log(colour); 
     } 
 })
```

Comment: Thanks to @Ashish 's answer and making a small modification, this would be the solution:

`
function colour() {
 $("#table tbody tr").each(function() {
  if ($(this).find('button').attr('boolean') == "true") {
   $(this).css("backgroundColor","red");
  } 
 })
}
`
Thank you!